# Error: "package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind does not exist" when compiling Java file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jackson, jackson-databind

I have created a Maven project on Eclipse and have added the following dependency on the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xml-databind</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I use the following code to check if the dependency can be compiled:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class App 
{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
    }

}
```

Although Eclipse does not show any error, when I compile it using the following commands:

```
$ javac -sourcepath src  src\main\java\App.java
```

I recieve the following 3 errors:

```
src\main\java\App.java:6: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind does not exist
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
                                     ^
src\main\java\App.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                ^
  symbol:   class ObjectMapper
  location: class App
src\main\java\App.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                                          ^
  symbol:   class ObjectMapper
  location: class App
3 errors
```

*Keep in mind that the corresponding JAR files to the dependancies are installed into the maven repository on the computer*

Comment: You are not compiling with maven, but with `javac`. So It expects those jar files to be on classpath not in mvn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your project is maven based, use maven command to compile it:
cd to directory that contains pom.xml and run:
mvn compile

Comment: I did it, and now how can I run the main class using the command window?

Comment: to run it: mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.app.App"